Argument for relationship between density of states and degrees of freedom and energy
From Reif's Fundamentals of Statistical and Thermal Physics chapter 2.5 Behaviour of the density of states:  Can anyone give a clear explanation for why the density of varies rapidly as Energy ($E$) and degrees of freedom ($f$) increase (i.e. # of states between E and deltaE varies as $E^f$)?
Either a clearly explanation of Reif's approach or an entirely different (and elementary) one would helpful.

It would be helpful to include Reif's approach in your question because without the book it's hard to answer this.

To add to the valid comment above: Please do so by typing the relevant passage (possibly using MathJax), not by using screenshots/images.

Reif (in [Fundamentals of Statistical and Thermal Physics], page 61)
considers a system of $f$ degrees of freedom and then goes on to treat this as a quantum system described by $f$ quantum numbers. One can dispute whether this is the correct meaning of $f$ degrees of freedom, but it is the reasoning he uses.
Reif explicitly states that "we are not interested in any exact results, but rather in a rough estimate adequate to reveal the essential behavior", of the density of states $\Omega(E)$ as a function of energy.
He then uses a few assumptions to reach his result, namely:

That each quantum number "contributes an amount of energy", so the total energy is more or less the addition of the energy of each quantum number.
The number of values one quantum number can have to contribute less than an amount $\epsilon$ of energy is roughly proportional to this energy
to a power close to $1$, "without getting involved in insignificant details", the text adds. Using Reif's equation numbering:
$$ \Phi_1 \propto \epsilon^\alpha \qquad(\alpha \approx 1) \tag{2.5.2}$$
For the total system, the energy $E$ will consist of  approximately equal contributions from all $f$ quantum numbers, each contributing $\epsilon \approx E/f $.
Without doing very precise math (but this step is easy to make rigorous) he then concludes:
$$ \Phi(E)\approx [\Phi_1(\epsilon)]^f, \qquad
 \text{where}\ \epsilon \approx \frac E f \tag{2.5.4}
$$

The definitions and assumptions used here are not substantiated any further in the text, and the example given subsequently is rather trivial: the ideal gas in the classical limit. Obviously the whole treatment is not completely rigorous (but I remember that as students, we still found Reif's book much more rigorous than our lecture notes).
At the very least the ideal gas could have been treated with the Schrodinger equation, using the fact that the density of eigenstates is independent of the shape of the container and proportional to the volume [as proven by Weyl]. (NB: that proof is apparently difficult, since Lorentz had tried but failed to find it!) The [generalizations] of the Weyl law can then also serve for more complicated systems, like the non-ideal electron gas in metals, so that might be one possible road to the more elementary proof discussed at the end of the question.
